# Как определить точные координаты нажатой кнопки в ячейке recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

Есть лента новостей с постами. В каждом посте (т.е. ячейке ленты) есть кнопка. Если пользователь нажимает эту кнопку, то должно в этом месте наложиться всплывающее меню (как в приложении пинтерест, когда пользователь зажимает на посте долго и всплывают кнопки, только в моём случае это не случайное место поста, а конкретная кнопка).
Так вот, чтобы поместить меню в то место где пользователь нажал на кнопку, мне надо знать абсолютные координаты этого места. Как мне узнать эти координаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно для элементов списка (вы ведь используете Holder'ы) при создании на кнопки вешать обычные `OnTouchListener`, которые будут хранить последнюю нажатую координату

Comment: Спасибо. А можете подсказать как именно вытащить последнюю нажатую координату? Я так понял надо при срабатывании нажатия обратиться к view и там вызвать какой-то метод, который вернёт координаты? Но какой именно метод?

Comment: У [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) в методе вторым аргументом идёт [MotionEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html). У последнего есть методы getX ([1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)), [2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX())) и getY ([1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY(int)), [2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getY()))

Comment: Как оказалось это не совсем то что мне было нужно. Мне нужны координаты нажатия относительно всего экрана, а не внутри самого элемента. Можно ли как-то сконвертировать эти координаты в абсолютные?

Comment: Можно навесить обработчик с запоминанием последней нажатой координаты на окно, а при нажатии на кнопку создать внутри окна в точке последнего нажатия вьюху, которую вы планировали создавать

Comment: Я методом тыка нашёл, что можно вызвать getRawX() (ну и соответственно для Y)

Comment: О, полезненько:)

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю, зачем вам нужны координаты? `PopupMenu` вешается к конкретной вьюшке, которую вы указываете в конструкторе `PopupMenu` - передавайте туда ваш `Button` и будет вам счастье...

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем вы. У меня есть recyclerview, в котором есть кнопки. При нажатии на кнопку, открывается написанная мною активити, где я сам реализовал всплывающее меню. Оно должно отобразиться в месте нажатия. Поэтому мне надо знать координаты нажатия. Благодаря человеку, чей ответ я принял, я теперь знаю как это сделать.